# Setting polygonOption styles for Fusion Table with Multiple Layers per Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have set two layers on my map.
I used the advice given here:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/multiple_layers_per_map

When I load the map I want certain polygons from layer 1 to be filled different colors according to a field value and pins from certain records from layer 2 given different colours according to a field value.

This is what I have working so far...
But placing Style statement before the map: map line does not work...

```js
function initialize_1() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4, -0.1),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Initialize the first layer
  var firstLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'LAD10CD',
      from: '1vWDu0FYiPNYEg6ZjLOOtNd6RYd1E_mWr-i5obblp',
      where: 'LAD10CD like \'E0%\''
    },
    //This is the type of style I am trying to add:
    //styles:[{where: 'LAD10CD like \'E0%\'', polygonOptions:{fillcolor:'#000000'}}]
    styles:[
      {where: 'LAD10CD like \'E09%\'', 'polygonOptions':{'fillColor':'#00ff00'}},
      {where: 'LAD10CD like \'E07%\'', 'polygonOptions':{'fillColor':'#0000ff'}}
    ],
//    Where can I find the styleId ?
//    styleId: 3,
    
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: false
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(firstLayer, 'click', function(e) {
    windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
  });

  // Initialize the second layer
  var secondLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'lat',
      from: '1Pe6lQx3KaFyP5pbhxWfERVciEuqYyBv1Dmcc_f5N',
      where: 'ClinicType Like \'%\''
    },
    //
    styleId: 2,
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: false
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(secondLayer, 'click', function(e) {
    windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
  });

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Google Maps API Example: Loacal Authorities Layer</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v3.24&MyKey=WentInHere"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--Insert the javascript below, if you are trying this code-->
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize_1()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here is my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ctdh/mL0zrn9k

Comment: I see a javascript error in your fiddle: `Uncaught TypeError: map.addLayer is not a function` if I run `initialize_2()`.  But your fiddle by default runs initialize_1() which doesn't do any styling.

Comment: I was trying a different approach with initialize_2()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use the styles, you can try this:

```
styles: [{where:'LAD10CD like \'E09%\'', 'polygonOptions': {'fillColor': '#000000'}}],
```

I think, in your code some aphostropes were missing.
On the other hand I could not set the fill color using the corresponding field value. 
But at the fusiontables you can create a styled map where you can set the 'FillColour' field to the polygon's fill color.

There is a styled map already called 'Map of geometry' and its ID is 3. If you create more maps you can watch their IDs at the en of the URL. (map:id=)
So you can use this ID as a 'styleId' like this:

```
var firstLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'LAD10CD',
  from: '1vWDu0FYiPNYEg6ZjLOOtNd6RYd1E_mWr-i5obblp',
  where: 'LAD10CD like \'E09%\''
},
styleId: 3,
map: map,
suppressInfoWindows: true
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful - the first styles, statement works nicely.  But styleId: 3 does not seem to work on a similar fusion table.

Comment: Maybe you should create a new map 'tab' at the Fusion tables and set the feature styles.

Comment: the styleID does not appear to come from the fusion table url querystring map:id=3, when I try using styleId:3 with another fusion table that has map:id=3 in the map's url it is ignored whereas I try styleId:2 and that works.  Where can I find the styleId?

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of styles: [{where...}, {where...}}] clauses I can include in a styles statement?  Clauses after the fifth where clause appear to be ignored...!?

Comment: I have made a research for you, but unfortunately I do not have good news. As the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#fusion_table_styles)  says:

Comment: "Styles can only be applied to a single Fusion Tables layer per map. You may apply up to five styles to that layer."  Anyway, you can list the table's styles [here] (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/style/list#try-it)

Comment: Hmmm apply multiple layers for each group of five styles or create the styles in a styleId in a FusionTable maps.

Comment: Style ID can be found here:
Required with New look. Click Tools > Publish. Enter the number after "y=" at the end of either URL.

Template ID can be found here:
Required with New look. Click Tools > Publish. Enter the number after "tmplt=" at the end of either URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MKiss for the info...
To create multi-layered Google maps based on FusionTables and control the styles of the layers:

Use the snippet in the OP
Option 1: Up to five where clauses can be included in each layer using:

```
styles: [{where:'LAD10CD like \'E09%\'', 'polygonOptions': {'fillColor': '#000000'}}],
```

Option 2:: Create the style in a FusionTable map and use the styleId of the  FusionTable map in the multi layered map script.  The styleId for a FusionTable map can be found in the FusionTable | Tools | Publish 'Send link to email or IM' the Style ID is number after the y= in the publish URL:

```
styleId: 3,
```